# How to find the amount of numbers above the average WHILE inputing the numbers?

Tags: c, average

This question is very tricky actually. Our teacher wants us to write a program (in C) that gets an unknown amount of numbers from the user (until the user enters -1) and that counts the amount of numbers above the average **WHILE INPUTING THE NUMBERS**. The thing that makes this task hard is the fact that we are NOT allowed to use arrays. I tried to calculate the rate of change in the averages and come up with a conclusion about our guess regarding the amount of numbers that are no longer above the average when the user enters a certain "big" number, but nothing came up to my mind. I just don't know how this thing can be programmed without actually saving the numbers somewhere and checking them after the final number has been inputed. I don't even know if it's possible. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've misunderstood the teacher, they are playing a trick on you, or they don't understand their own problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106700/incremental-averageing (in short save the sum of the numbers and how many numbers you have read so far, thats enough)

Comment: @SamBob Perhaps you've not read the problem all the way through. They are asking how to print the  _count_ of numbers above average after each number is read. And they aren't allowed to save the numbers. This doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Agreeing with all three previous comments: you can only count the numbers that are above the incremental average at the time that number is entered. You cannot determine the count of numbers that are above the final average of all the numbers.

Comment: I believe the teacher wants you to use dynamic allocation instead of "normal" arrays.

Comment: My bad, that does seem impossible (unless you "cheat" and store numbers not technically in an array, such as to raw offsets in malloc'd memory or a file)

Comment: *"I just don't know how this thing can be programmed without actually saving the numbers somewhere"* and *"we are NOT allowed to use arrays"* are actually not the same thing. You need to clarify with the teacher which of those is the correct problem statement. There are lots of ways to store numbers without using arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible without keeping an amount of information proportional to the number of inputs, thus essentially requiring arrays.

Proof: Consider any sequence of *n*−1 inputs followed by a final input *x*. For illustration, suppose the set of allowed inputs is the rational numbers. By selecting *x*, we can make the average any rational number. (If the sum of the first *n*−1 inputs is *s* and we want the average to be *a*, then we select *x* = *an*−*s*.) So, we can select an *x* that is very slightly below 1 and that is very slightly above 1, and therefore the program must “know” whether 1 is in the prior inputs so that it can be included in the count. Similarly, we can select an *x* that is very slightly below or above any other number, and the program must respond accordingly. So the only way for the program to be able to produce a correct count for all possible inputs is if it has a record of all prior inputs.

Comment: Why are arrays required to keep info on all the inputs?  Given the problem, a binary tree is probably better than an array anyways,

Answer (score 0):

I believe that teacher is trying to teach you how to use `malloc` family functions.

I would do it this way:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    int data[];
}data_type;

size_t countAbove(const data_type *data, int val)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < data -> size; i++) count += data -> data[i] > val;
    return count;
}

int getAverage(const data_type *data)
{
    long long sum = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < data -> size; i++) sum += data -> data[i];
    return sum / data -> size;
}

data_type *addData(data_type *data, int val)
{
    size_t newsize = data ? data -> size + 1 : 1;

    data = realloc(data, sizeof(*data) + newsize * sizeof(data -> data[0]));
    if(data)
    {
        data -> data[newsize - 1] = val;
        data -> size = newsize;
    }
    return data;
}

int main(void)
{
    data_type *data = NULL, *tmp;
    int val = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter number: ");
        while(scanf("%d", &val) != 1);
        if(val == -1) break;
        printf("\n");
        tmp = addData(data, val);
        if(tmp) data = tmp;
        else { /* add some error handling*/}
        printf("Numbers above average %zu\n", countAbove(data, getAverage(data)));
    }
    free(data);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TzzjffbT9